# Nhibernate Distinct with Order By (Oracle DB)

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, queryover

I have this old project that needs refactoring.
I started rewriting some queries using the newest version of Nhibernate.
I have this query that needs to return a paged distinct list of Id's with an order by.
Problem is that you can't seem to do an order by on properties that aren't included in the select statement. But I don't want to select other columns I only want the id's.

Is there a way to make sure i only get the Id's and still get a paged distinct list?

This is a simplified version of what I have now:

```
Student student = null;
Locker locker = null;
Teacher teacher = null;
Grade grade = null;

var baseQuery = SessionHandler.CurrentSession.QueryOver(() => student)
    .JoinAlias(() => cat.Locker, () => locker)
    .JoinAlias(() => cat.Teachers, () => teacher)
    .JoinAlias(() => cat.Grades, () => grade));

if (gender.HasValue)
{
    baseQuery.Where(() => student.Gender == gender.Value);
}

if (hallway.HasValue)
{
    baseQuery.Where(() => locker.Hallway == hallway.Value);
}

...

baseQuery.Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() =>     student.StudentId)));
baseQuery.OrderBy(b => student.Birthday, OrderSettings.Direction);
var results = baseQuery.Skip(50).Take(50).List<TKey>();
```

Code like this always throws a ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression.
Does anybody know how to fix this using a subquery or something else?
I am not used to Nhibernate so I really got no clue.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL itself, you can not sort (put in order by clause) on the column which is not there in the select clause.

Please let me know why do you need sorting on DatumInplanning when you just need the StudentId? You can also optionally use the raw SQL syntax if needed.

```
var query = "SELECT TOP 10000 o.* "
            + " from ORDERS o where o.Year in (:orderYear));";

var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
var result =session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                .AddEntity(typeof(Order))
                .SetInt32("orderYear",2012)
                .List<Order>();
```

There is no way in SQL you can do this. You must have the column name in select **distinct** clause if putting the order by. Here are alternatives for you.

1) Get both columns in the results and do manipulation in your application to get exact data you want.

2) Change to custom SQL like following ( sub SQL). I tested this in Oracle. It worked well.

```
select ID from (select  ID from student order by Birthday);
```

However, there is business result problem when you do distinct sort on column which is not there in order by clause. Please see illustration below. ID 2 belongs to birthdates 4,6,8. So when you do order by birthdate, and get the ID distinct results will not be consistent. Give me your table structure and the results that you want to fetch. Let me give chance if I can fix it from SQL side.

```
SQL> select id,birthdate from student order by birthdate;

        ID BIRTHDATE
---------- ---------
         0 29-AUG-15
         5 29-AUG-15
         1 03-SEP-15
         2 04-SEP-15
         3 06-SEP-15
         2 06-SEP-15
         2 08-SEP-15

7 rows selected.

SQL> select distinct id from (select id,birthdate from student order by birthdat
e);

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         5
         3
         0
```

3) Do not put distinct clause and you should be able to filter it by Birthday.

Comment: Sorry for the Dutch propery, I changed DatumInplanning to BirthDay now.
I need the order by because of the paging. These id's are used for another select but i only select 50 each time and they need to be in the exact order as i want to display them on the screen.

Comment: I have answered by editing my earlier answered. Please review and let me know if this resolves your problem

Comment: I know this works but we need a distinct also.
Because a lot of tables are joined (to do some filtering) there are duplicates in the results. But once you da a distinct it will fail unless you use subqueries but i can't seem to figure out how to get this to work in Nhibernate.

Comment: Answer edited above. With 1 illustration explaining if you put sort distinct for column which is not in select could also give wrong business result.